# How to remove each item that appears in first collection from second collection using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Suppose I have 2 collections:

1) `{1, 2, 3, 5}`
2) `{2, 5}`

I want to remove each item that appears in second collection from first collection, so I will get:

```
{1, 3}
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I do this with `Join` OP (better with extension methods syntax)?
2. And is there any way I can iterate over two collections as I do with nested for/foreach loops?

**Edits:**
To iterate over two collections simultaneously You can use nested `from` clauses:

```
from boy in boys
from girl in girls
select boy + "+" + girl
```

First time I found this syntax necessary :)

Comment: Why with `Join`? It doesn't need `Join` at all :)

Comment: any ideas how to iterate over two collections simultaneously? Not in the context of current problem, but I'm just wondering, cause in many cases I need this feature

Comment: compare each item from first collection with item from second colleciton

Comment: Compare how? what's the exact return you want to obtain?

Comment: For instance, I have a collection of strings and I need to build a collection of chars that appear in each string, so I need to iterate over collection of all characters and for each char check that it appeares in each string from the first collection. I would do it with 2 foreach/for loops, but is it possible to accomplish this using Linq?

Comment: Or I need to get every possible pair of items from two collections: itemFromCollection1+itemFromCollection2 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what you need

```
var solution = list1.Except(list2);
```

You can find more details about Except [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx), but the basic idea is:

> This method returns those elements in first that do not appear in
>   second. It does not also return those elements in second that do not
>   appear in first.

Comment: I'm a fool) Have forgotten this method) Thanks!

Comment: I will accept Your answer as it was first. BTW ToList method will execute the query which is not needed most of the time

Comment: I'll remove the ToList if that's not how you want your data to be returned :)

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
var newList = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```